# How do I update an XML column in SQL Server using modify?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following value in an XML data type column of a SQL Server table:

```
<feed>
  <schedule>
    <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="monday" addDays="1" time="02:00:00"/>
    <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="tuesday" addDays="1" time="02:00:00"/>
    <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="wednesday" addDays="1" time="02:00:00"/>
    <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="thursday" addDays="1" time="02:00:00"/>
    <arrivalSla dayOfWeek="friday" addDays="3" time="12:45:00"/>
  </schedule>
  <assetCode value="FI" />
</feed>
```

I want to update the time attribute where `dayOfWeek="friday"` to "11:00:00". I have tried various ways, including the following, but get an error of

> XQuery [learnTheXML.xnlColumn.modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'element(arrivalSla,xdt:untyped) *'

```
UPDATE learnTheXML
SET xmlColumn.modify('replace value of (/feed/schedule/arrivalSla[@dayOfWeek="friday"]) with "11:00:00"')
WHERE id = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The point where you start wanting to filter on or update XML details within the column is the point where should consider extracting those values to into their own columns in the schema, and updating the application to maintain that data at INSERT/UPDATE time. This will **greatly** improve performance, often by _multiple orders of magnitude!_

Comment: Thanks, point well-taken. I just needed to whip up a quick test with some new values, but I will definitely keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to provide a singleton value to update and also you need to tell it you want to update (presumably) the value of `time`:

```sql
UPDATE learnTheXML
SET xmlColumn.modify('replace value of (/feed/schedule/arrivalSla[@dayOfWeek="friday"]/@time)[1] with "11:00:00"')
WHERE id = 1;
```